# Status of ssas cube database during cube processing

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssas-2008

I am using ssas2008. I have a report that is based on this particular cube. Some time when my clients try to execute the report they got some missing information inside the ssrs report.
My question is during the cube processing time, what happend with its ssas database. Can we still query it during the cube processing or not?

Please answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your report is querying the cube whilst processing the data is not available.

If you mean the relational database is being queried during cube processing then query response may be slow or time out as ssas will be acquiring locks on data.